# How can I set the tick label style to scientific?

Tags: python, matplotlib, surface, scatter

I am pretty new to python and I am currently struggling with a simple plotting Problem. I am trying to plot a scatter plot on 3D axes with 3 one-dimensional Arrays. Everything I found tutorialwise seems straight forward so I wrote this code:

```
def ThreeDScatter():    

    dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog(directory=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
    dialog.exec_()
    FileName = dialog.selectedFiles()[0]

    Test=pandas.read_csv(FileName)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    X = Test.ix[:,"a"]
    Y = Test.ix[:,"b"]
    Z = Test.ix[:,"c"]
    ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c='r', marker='o', s=2, edgecolors='red');
    ax.set_xlabel('a')
    ax.set_ylabel('b')
    ax.set_zlabel('c')

    plt.show()

    ThreeDScatter()
```

When I run this code I am expecting the tick labels to have a format like: 1e6, 2e6, 3e6 or similar.

But instead I get the following: [image: Test Plot]

Additionally I was wondering if there is a simple way of transforming this scatter plot into a surface plot with a Kind of Interpolation between the Points? The workarounds I found by googling (numpy.meshgrid) confused me a bit.

If anybody could help a python newbie I would really appreciate it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.ticklabel_format) and the full docs of the 2d-equivalent [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format).

Comment: Hey Sasha, thanks for your quick help. I had a look at the documentation and I tried quite a few things with the ScalarFormatter and ticklabel_Format but unfortunately the labels are not changing at all. The last thing I tried looks like it is redundant but even this didn't change anything. matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter().set_scientific(True)
    ax = ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis = 'both')

Comment: If you had provided an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with generated data, it's likely that more people would have tried to answer this. Personally, I had it marked as a question to look at, but my first step would have been to duplicate it, and, 1) that takes needless effort, 2) if it's a system setting (eg, your rcParams file) then I wouldn't be able to duplicate it but wouldn't know that for sure (but if I ran code that did it for you and it didn't on my system, then I'd know in a few seconds that it was a settings issue).

Comment: I am sorry, I guess I need to learn some things if I want to participate on this community here ;). Please excuse me.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvDLJU3fTLwtxSnk4ezz4IJX7BmA
     I uploaded a testfile with which the code should be executable and it should display my issue.